# Using DownloadManager for incognito downloads

Tags: android, android-download-manager

Can I use android.app.DownloadManager to download files that will be accessible (and visible) only to my application?

The solution should work for API 9 (2.3), if there is a 3rd party library that will achieve the same as DM then please let me know as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. By default, downloads are saved to a generated filename in the shared download cache and may be deleted by the system at any time to reclaim space.

You can register a BroadcastReceiver to get notified when the download is complete. In this receiver, you can get the path of the downloaded file and copy it to internal storage yourself. Then, you can delete the file from the default path.

See [this tutorial](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/) for an example about receiving a download complete broadcast and responding to it.

Comment: IT is some sort of workaround but I was more interested in limiting access to the files for user. With DM it goes to the notification area and user can also get all downloads. And I want to limit this access to only the application that requested the download, in  other words use DM to do the hard work of downloading/reattempting etc. but only my app has access and will manage the file.

Comment: maybe you know DM replacement that I could use and will have this behaviour

Comment: You can use the `setNotificationVisibility` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setNotificationVisibility(int)) method to hide the notification from the user. This method is only available from API 11 though.

Comment: Yes, I should mention that the solution must work from API level 9, thanks

Comment: In that case, you're probably gonna have to roll your own solution I suppose.